# Convolution in Hopf algebras

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, convolution, abelian-categories, hopf-algebras

For each Hopf algebra $H$ its space ${\mathcal L}(H)$ of operators $A:H\to H$ [is usually endowed with the operation of convolution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521558840) by the identity
$$
A*B = \mu \circ (A\otimes B)\circ \varDelta
$$
where $\mu$ is the multiplication, $\varDelta$ the comultiplication in $H$, and $A,B\in{\mathcal L}(H)$.

Can anybody advise me a text where this notion is described in detail? I wonder, in particular, which identities connect $A*B$ with the usual operation $A\circ B$ of composition of operators.

Comment: Sergei, i have added i couple of tags. But if you disagree feel free to retag.

Comment: No, it's OK! I agree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try "Hopf algebras. An introduction" by Dascalescu, Nastasescu, Raianu. They have a detailed account with full proofs and further examples and exercises.

Kassel's book "Quantum groups" and Sweedler's book on "Hopf algebras" (see esp. p. 69-79, 314-315) might also prove useful.

Finally, you might  find some interest at 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1980032/195021.

**Edit:** Motivated by your question on the relation between convolution and the composition, i could not find some direct reference, however i recalled some old notes of mine and found the following relations (in what follows, $\mu$, $\Delta$, $\eta$, $\varepsilon$, $S$, stand for the corresponding multiplication, comultiplication, unity, counity and antipode maps respectively):

1. **the composition distributes over convolution**: i.e. if $f,g\in Hom(F,G)$, $p\in Hom(H,F)$ where $H,F,G$ are Hopf algebras and $Hom(.,.)$ stands for the corresponding Hopf algebra maps, then:
   $$
   \boxed{ (f\star g)\circ p=(f\circ p)\star(g\circ p) }
   $$
   **Proof:** by definition: 
   $$
   (f\star g)\circ p=\mu_G\circ(f\otimes g)\circ\Delta_F \circ p
   $$ 
   and 
   $$
   (f\circ p)\star(g\circ p)=\mu_G\circ\big((f\circ p)\otimes (g\circ p)\big)\circ\Delta_H = \mu_G\circ (f\otimes g)\circ (p\otimes p)\circ\Delta_H =\\=\mu_G\circ(f\otimes g)\circ\Delta_F\circ p
   $$
   where in the last line we have made use of the fact that since $f,g,p$ are assumed to be Hopf algebra morphisms they are also coalgebra morphisms and thus $\Delta_F \circ p=(p\otimes p)\circ\Delta_H$.
2. **$f\circ S_F=S_G\circ f$, is the $\star$-inverse of $f$**, i.e.:
   $$
   \boxed{ (S_G\circ f)\star f=f\star(S_G\circ f)=\eta_G\circ\varepsilon_F}   
   $$
   **Proof:**  Applying the definition of the convolution we get: 
   $$
   \big((S_G\circ f)\star f\big)=\mu_G\circ\big((S_G\circ f)\otimes f\big)\circ\Delta_F=  
   \mu_G\circ(S_G\otimes Id)\circ(f\otimes f)\circ\Delta_F=\\=\mu_G\circ(S_G\otimes Id)\circ\Delta_G\circ f=\eta_G\circ\varepsilon_G\circ f=\eta_G\circ\varepsilon_F
   $$
   where we have used:
   $\bullet \ (f\otimes f)\circ\Delta_F=\Delta_G\circ f$, because $f\in Hom(F,G)$,
   $\bullet \ \mu_G\circ(S_G\otimes Id)\circ\Delta_G=\eta_G\circ\varepsilon_G$, by the definition of the antipode,
   $\bullet \ \varepsilon_G\circ f=\varepsilon_F$, because $f\in Hom(F,G)$.
3. A more general property, which has a categorical "flavor" and is related to the preceding properties, is the following one:

   > Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Category of commutative, cocommutative, finite dimensional Hopf algebras. Let the corresponding Hom-sets $\mathcal{H}om(F,G)$ be equipped with sum (convolution) and product (composition). Then, $\mathcal{H}$ becomes an abelian Category.
   >   (see Sweedler's book, sect. 16.2, p. 314-315, where this is result is cited).

   What is essentialy happening here, is that $\mathcal{H}om(F,G)$ becomes an abelian group -under convolution- with neutral element: 
   $\eta_G\circ\varepsilon_F$.
   Furthermore, it can be shown that there is an equivalence of abelian Categories, between the Category of commutative, cocommutative, finite dimensional Hopf algebras $\mathcal{H}$ and the category $\mathcal{Ab}_{fin}$ of the finite, abelian groups. It is possible to construct a fully faithful and essentially faithful functor between $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{Ab}_{fin}$. See more details on this point at: 
   [Reference on correspondence between commutative Hopf Algebras and Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767867/reference-on-correspondence-between-commutative-hopf-algebras-and-groups/2769249#2769249)

Comment: As far as I understand, Dascalescu, Nastasescu and Kassel prove this only for the Hopf algebras in the category of vector spaces, since they use the Sweedler notations. I thought there must be a general proof for all symmetric monoidal categories. Also are there any identities that connect $A*B$ with $A\circ B$?

Comment: @Sergei, i have updated the post including some more detailed info. Hope, it is more helpful now.

Comment: KonKan, that is interesting. Several notes: 1) in the first identity $f$ and $g$ seem to not be homomorphisms of Hopf algebras, just morphisms in the given category, 2) I don't understand how you prove the second identity, 3) this needs to be published.

Comment: Sergei, I have added the proof of the second identity and some more details in 3).

Comment: KonKan, thank you! You should publish all this in a book.

Comment: @Sergei, while these are essentially not new results, i agree that they are not well known and they are not readily available in the literature. Writting a book on Hopf algebras is a serious and long term project. These results are included (in a somewhat expanded form)  in my Phd thesis and in some (unpublished) lecture notes of mine. However, both texts are in greek.

Comment: Do you have in mind some suitable venue of publication (in english) which might be interested for such stuff?

Comment: KonKan, excuse me, I could not reply earlier. I think Dissertaciones mathematicae or Journal of Mathematical Sciences could publish such a monograph. This depends on the content of course, but if the text is clear and (at least) some results are new, they could be interested. You can send me your dissertation, we could discuss this.

Comment: Sergei, thank you very much for your feedback. I am considering your suggestion as a very good idea. However, since my dissertation and the lecture notes are both written in greek, it will take some time to prepare a version in english. I expect  to come back to you in a couple of months. I intend to be in touch in any case!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget also about arxiv.org.

Comment: KonKan, my advise is that you should formulate and prove everything for maximally general case, i.e. for Hopf algebras in arbitrary symmetrical (or braided?) monoidal category, because (as far as I can see) this is absent in existing textbooks.

Comment: I think that quite interesting questions can be posed on the interplay between preadditive/additive/abelian Categories on the one hand and symmetric/braided/monoidal on the other. And the hopf algebras/quantum groups setting seems quite a natural "playground" for such research. I am not aware of many examples on that direction.

Comment: We can discuss/share the examples. My wish is that the categories should be maximally abstract.

Comment: KonKan, also I think we should contact directly by email. My address is here: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=8763&option_lang=eng

Comment: Sergei, i agree. I will send you an email soon so that you also have my address.